# PHP curl get negotiated TLS version

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am trying to check whether my requests are using TLS version >1. While curl command line gives me this information in the verbose output, php does not seem to be.

This is my PHP curl verbose output when the connection is initiated

```
* About to connect() to *** port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 88.*.*.*... * connected
* Connected to *** (88.*.*.*) port 443 (#0)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: ***
*   start date: Dec 21 18:43:21 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Dec 21 18:38:18 2016 GMT
*   common name: ***
*   issuer: CN=Verizon Akamai SureServer CA G14-SHA2,OU=Cybertrust,O=Verizon Enterprise Solutions,L=Amsterdam,C=NL
* Server auth using Basic with user '***'
> GET /my/path HTTP/1.1
Authorization: ***
Host: ***
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: ***
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 3733
< Expires: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 15:24:49 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 15:24:49 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host *** left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

How can I say what is the TLS used in a connection? I would like to avoid using any 3rd party options like making request to https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: I am trying to check whether my requests are using TLS version >1. So I am looking for a way to learn what is the TLS version of the current curl connection